# Word choice in this passage

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, sentence-construction, clauses

I take an exam yesterday and I think reject from this exam. Anyway, here is one of passages from the exam:

> Thunder is caused by lightning, which is essentially a stream of
>   electrons ﬂowing between or within clouds or between a cloud and the
>   ground. The air surrounding the electron stream becomes **so** hot—up to
>   50,000 degrees Fahrenheit—that it forms a resonating tube of partial
>   vacuum **surrounding** the lightning’s path. Alternative choices for the bold words in above text are as follows:

---

> a)‌very, so, too, enough
>
> b) surrounding, surrounds, that surround, and surround

The original text had blanks in place of the bold words, but this text has the solutions. Could anyone describe in short detail why these words were selected?

Comment: Hey Moji. Sorry about your test. I'm sure you'll do better next time. I've voted to move your question over to our sister site, [ELL.se], which is dedicated to helping people learn English.

Comment: Would you please move it? @DanBron

Comment: Yep. It will take a few more votes, so give it a little time.

Comment: This really should be separate questions. Explaining each choice will have a different reason and the way our site works, it is best that each question be asked individually. I recommend that you break this up into separate questions, otherwise we may close it as being too broad.

Comment: @Catija why angry with me? you means I ask it in 5 question now? I think this answer can made from 5 short part here.

Comment: I'm not angry. I'm explaining how this site works. Questions must be asked one at a time so that the best answers can be given and voted on. If you have five questions in one, one answer may be correct for parts of the question but incorrect for others, which makes it impossible to vote on the answers. To help prevent this, it is necessary to ask questions individually.

Comment: @Catija Ok would you please learn me how break this question with one passage?

Comment: You can also help us out by explaining which answers you think are correct and why. If we know which ones you know are wrong, we don't need to take time explaining why those answers are incorrect. Show us the effort you've put into figuring this out yourself.

Comment: Use the [edit] button to edit your question. I recommend copying the entire question into a text editor so that you can reuse it easily. Then, remove the four other parts of the question and add additional details as I've mentioned in my previous comment. Editing will also bring your question more views.  For the other questions, you will need to use the "ask question" button to create a new question. Because you are a new user, you may be limited in how many questions you can ask in a day, so you may have to ask them gradually.

Answer (score 1):

> The air surrounding the electron stream becomes **so** hot—up to 50,000 degrees Fahrenheit—that it forms a resonating tube of partial vacuum **surrounding** the lightning’s path.

A) "So" can be used **before adjectives or other adverbs** to *precede a subordinate clause* expressing the **result of** a great **extent** of the adjective or adverb.

Your sentence is explaining that the electron stream reaches an **extremely** hot temperature; **because** it got that hot, **something happens**: the resonating tube is formed.

To make more examples of the construction:

> He would abuse her **so** *much* **that** she *got used* to it.
>   The cake was **so** *delicious* **that** I *couldn't resist eating* more.

The other choices simply aren't used to make this construction, so they're all wrong except "so", which is used.

B)

> it forms a resonating tube of partial vacuum **surrounding** the lightning’s path.

It's pretty much the same reason as some of these other sentences in the very same paragraph:

> Thunder is caused by lightning, which is essentially a stream of electrons **ﬂowing** between or within clouds or between a cloud and the ground. The air **surrounding** the electron stream becomes so hot—up to 50,000 degrees Fahrenheit—that it forms a resonating tube of partial vacuum **surrounding** the lightning’s path.

These are **participle phrases**, which add **detail about what** *the thing described by the phrase* **is doing**.

In your example, **what is** the resonating tube **doing**? It is **surrounding** the lightning's path.

Let's prove that the other options are wrong, then.

> that surround, and surround

These are ungrammatical as these are verbs that **the tube (singular) serves as their subject**. *Verbs with third-person-singular subjects must use their own form in the present tense*, which ends with an S (e.g. surround**s**).

---

> surrounds

Even then:

> it forms a resonating tube of partial vacuum surrounds the lightning’s path.

It would sound like an unfinished relative clause. Relative clauses are clauses used by English speakers when adding information that tells you **what *that* tube is doing**, to go by example. Relative clauses must use a relative pronoun (e.g. "that", "who") **that** is missing in your example. Therefore, "surrounds" is not an answer.

However,

> it forms a resonating tube of partial vacuum **that surrounds** the lightning’s path.

would be fine.